# Where does an R core dump go?

Tags: r, ubuntu, coredump

My R session crashed with this:

> Process R segmentation fault (core dumped) at Tue Jan  6 11:29:24 2015

I'm running R 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 13.10 (yes I need to upgrade).  I'm not worried about the crash, but I want to find the core dump.  It's not in the R working directory, it's not in `/var/crash` or `/var/cache`, and I don't know where else to look.

On edit:  my `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` reads `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c`.  `apport` doesn't have a man page, but I can google it, and it looks like it's supposed to write the core to `/var/crash`, but it's not there.  Could R be overriding the default core dump behavior?

Comment: Have you looked in the R process's current working directory?

Comment: Also check the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to see where the core files are written (or piped to).

Comment: It's not in the current working directory.  `core_pattern` indicates that it is piped to `apport`, which doesn't seem to have a man page.

Comment: This is a syadmin issue. Ask your sysadmin what `apport` is.

Comment: There is no sysadmin.  I just want to find where the core dump went.  I was hoping another R user had done this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html). On some Linux, name and location of `core` is configurable thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), e.g. with `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. See also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (so, your shell's `ulimit` builtin). Check that your core limit is a few hundred megabytes at least.

BTW, you could write into that `core_pattern` file and repeat the offending R session.

Comment: `core_pattern` indicates that it is piped into `apport`.  `man apport` comes up blank.  Is it possible that R is overriding the default core dump behavior and putting it somewhere else?

Comment: it's very very unlikely.  Perhaps you have a `ulimit` set to 0 that is stopping the core file from being written? Try `ulimit -c` and see what you get ...

Comment: `ulimit -c` returns `0`.  If the core didn't get written, that's probably OK.  Part of what I'm worried about is that the core could be huge and eat up my hard drive.  I have 500G of RAM and often use a lot of it during big simulations.  Don't know how much RAM was in use when it dumped.

Comment: If you have 500G of RAM (that means a very expansive computer) you need to have enough disk for a 500G (or 300G) core dump. Don't hesitate to buy a new disk!

Comment: Yes, a big computer.  If the core didn't get written, that's OK, but I want to know about it.  What I don't want is a big 300G file somewhere that I don't know about.

Comment: You could use `find -size +120000` to find big files!

Comment: Good call with `find -size`.  No core dump larger than 1G, which in all likelihood means no core dump was saved.  Thanks for all your help.